# ReactJs UseState : insert element into array not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to use React Hooks but somehow my state is not updating. When I click on the checkbox (see in the example), I want the index of the latter to be added to the array `selectedItems`, and vice versa

My function looks like this:

```
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

const handleSelectMultiple = index => {
    if (selectedItems.includes(index)) {
        setSelectedItems(selectedItems.filter(id => id !== index));
    } else {
        setSelectedItems(selectedItems => [...selectedItems, index]);
    }
    console.log("selectedItems", selectedItems, "index", index);
};
```

You can find the `console.log` result
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g72wX.png)

An empty array in the result, can someone explain to me where I missed something ?

Comment: Actually there isn't a problem with your code. It's just that when you log `selectedItems` the state isn't updated yet.

Comment: `setSelectedItems ` is asynchronous, it will not update state immediately. You are getting stale state.

Comment: @hussain.codes , so what are instruction added, to have the current state of the array

Answer (score 3):

Because `useState` is asynchronous - you wont see an immediate update after calling it.

Try adding a `useEffect` which uses a dependency array to check when values have been updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedItems);
}, [selectedItems])
```

Comment: when I try useEffect and i log(selectedItems) I have the latest index added in the array not list of indexes, the problem that the concatenation of indexes does not do this correctly

Answer (score 0):

Actually there isn't a problem with your code. It's just that when you log `selectedItems` the state isn't updated yet.

If you need `selectedItems` exactly after you update the state in your function you can do as follow:

```
const handleSelectMultiple = index => {
    let newSelectedItems;
    if (selectedItems.includes(index)) {
        newSelectedItems = selectedItems.filter(id => id !== index);
    } else {
        newSelectedItems = [...selectedItems, index];
    }
    setSelectedItems(newSelectedItems);
    console.log("selectedItems", newSelectedItems, "index", index);
};
```

Comment: when i do this change montioned in my function , this is the result after adding 3 new indexes,
 
newSelectedItems [1] index 1
 newSelectedItems [2] index 2
 newSelectedItems [3] index 3 

the expected result => newSelectedItems[1,2,3] index 3 . it's like setSelectedItems() doesn't work, it doesn't update the array, it always keeps the initial state of the array

Comment: Can you post your entire component? I just tested it and it works fine.